# Having problem in C# getting value from an XML subnode

Tags: c#, xml

I am trying to loop through a subnode while looping through another node. The code I am using is (a lot of processing code not relevant to the question removed).

```
private void InsertLineItems(IEnumerable<XElement> BillingCode, int visitId)
{
    if (BillingCode != null)
    {
        using (var visitRepo = db.GetVisitRepository())
        {
            foreach (var item in BillingCode)
            {
                if (item.Element("Code").Attribute("value").Value.Length < 9)
                {
                    foreach (var icditem in item.Descendants("ICD10List"))
                    {
                        var icd10code = item.Element("ICD10List").Element("ICD10Code").Attribute("value");
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
)
```

To parse the following XML

```
<BillingCodes>
    <BillingCodeDTO>
        <Code value="73100"/>
        <Description value="X-ray left lower leg"/>
        <Quantity value="1"/>
        <ICD10List>
            <ICD10Code value="Y34.9"/>
            <ICD10Code value="Y34.99"/>
            <ICD10Code value="M79.9"/>
        </ICD10List>
    </BillingCodeDTO>
    <BillingCodeDTO>
        <Code value="74120"/>
        <Description value="X-ray left foot"/>
        <Quantity value="1"/>
        <ICD10List>
            <ICD10Code value="Z03.9"/>
        </ICD10List>
    </BillingCodeDTO>
</BillingCodes>
```

The problem I am getting is that while looping through the ICD10List it is only returning the first value. Where am I going wrong in getting it to loop through all the values?  I did try using the ICD10Code as the loop (code below, just changed the foreach), that looped the correct number of times but returned the same value each time.

```
  foreach (var icditem in item.Descendants("ICD10List").Descendants("ICD10Code"))
    { var icd10code = item.Element("ICD10List").Element("ICD10Code").Attribute("value");}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a) You only have one variable which you re-assign all over again. In the end you want to use a list or something.

b) you should make use of the `icditem` variable instead of accessing a fixed element. A good IDE would indicate a warning about an unused variable.

```
foreach (var icditem in item.Descendants("ICD10List").Descendants("ICD10Code"))
{ 
    var icd10code = icditem .Attribute("value");
}
```